# How to print a list

Tags: list, printing, sml, smlnj

I thought I read something about List.toString somewhere, but for `l = [1,2,3]; print (List.toString (l) )` I am getting `Error: unbound variable or constructor: toString in path List.tostring` and just `print l` gives me

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: string
  operand:         int list
  in expression:
    print a
```

So, how can I convert a list to string and print it then? This cannot be so hard, but when searching for how to just print a simple list I did not find an answer. In this case I have a list of ints.

I found this

```
fun f (x: int list) = (PolyML.print x; ());
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503405/print-int-list-in-sml).

But it gives me `Error: unbound structure: PolyML in path PolyML.print`

Comment: Take another look at the page you've linked to, it offers enough explanation in my opinion. PolyML is another SML compiler, that's you can't find that structure, it's not available in the SML/NJ compiler: http://www.polyml.org/

Comment: So, how do I print a list in SML/NJ?

Comment: You can't http://stackoverflow.com/a/36507598/58808

Answer (score 2):

Here is an SML version which can be used in SML/NJ:

```
fun printList xs = print(String.concatWith ", " (map Int.toString xs));
```

The function takes an int list, converts it to a list of string representations, and then joins the strings with ", ", finally printing the result.